# How pytorch implement forward for a quantized linear layer?

Tags: pytorch, quantization

I have a quantized model in pytorch and now I want to extract the parameter of the quantized linear layer and implement the forward manually.
I search the source code but only find this function.

```
def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    return torch.ops.quantized.linear(
    x, self._packed_params._packed_params, self.scale, self.zero_point)
```

But no where I can find how torch.ops.quantized.linear is defined.

Can someone give me a hind how the forward of quantized linear are defined?

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the question of where `torch.ops.quantized.linear` is, I was looking for the same thing but was never able to find it. I believe it's probably somewhere in the `aten` (C++ namespace). I did, however, find some useful PyTorch-based implementations in the NVIDIA TensorRT repo below. It's quite possible these are the ones actually called by PyTorch via some DLLs. If you're trying to add quantization to a custom layer, these implementations walk you through it.

You can find the [docs here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/pytorch-quantization-toolkit/docs/index.html) and the [GitHub page here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/tree/main/tools/pytorch-quantization).

For the linear layer specifically, see the [QuantLinear layer here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/blob/87f3394404ff9f9ec92c906cd4c39b5562aea42e/tools/pytorch-quantization/pytorch_quantization/nn/modules/quant_linear.py#L29)

Under the hood, this calls [TensorQuantFunction.apply()](https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/blob/87f3394404ff9f9ec92c906cd4c39b5562aea42e/tools/pytorch-quantization/pytorch_quantization/tensor_quant.py#L234) for post-training quantization or [FakeTensorQuantFunction.apply()](https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/blob/87f3394404ff9f9ec92c906cd4c39b5562aea42e/tools/pytorch-quantization/pytorch_quantization/tensor_quant.py#L298) for quantization-aware training.